# How to categorize this data by frequency of another column?

Tags: excel

I have several columns of data that need to be sorted into tables. What I would like is to go through each  purely numerical column on the left and "a" column of the right. With two columns fixed, extract all unique values from the value column (there could be any number of them, but no repeats). Then I want to count them according to their category: a0 or aN where N>0. There's a fixed number of categories. It should result in the following table:

[Example with test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ2Of.png)

(6 tables should be produced in all for this example)
It should work in Excel 2007 for compatibility reasons. How would this be done? Is a VBA macro necessary?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  What you have tried so far?

Comment: Using the Countifs function, but I need something more automated because my actual data has many more values and categories. Is there any more information I can provide that would be helpful in solving this problem?